# Want to concatenate the random uniformly generated values

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, dataframe

I have code as following and I want to write a function for it. output should be x as dataframe and y as series, even dataframe having x and y as columns is enough.

```
x = np.arange(0,50)
x = pd.DataFrame({'x':x})

# just random uniform distributions in differnt range

y1 = np.random.uniform(10,15,10)
y2 = np.random.uniform(20,25,10)
y3 = np.random.uniform(0,5,10)
y4 = np.random.uniform(30,32,10)
y5 = np.random.uniform(13,17,10)

y = np.concatenate((y1,y2,y3,y4,y5))
y = y[:,None]
```

I tried following but it doesn't return values from y1 to y5.
My code is :

```
x = np.arange(0,50)
x = pd.DataFrame({'x':x})
def colm(p,q):
    s, t = p, q
    a = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y5']
    for i in a:
        i = np.random.uniform(s, t, 10)
        s, t = s+10, t+10
        return i
```

Comment: How do you invoke your function?

Comment: The `return i` in the `for` loop in your function will exit the loop after only the first iteration, returning just one list of random uniform numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it after some try what I was looking for:

```
x = np.arange(0,50)
x = pd.DataFrame({'x':x})
def colm(p,q):
    s, t = p, q
    z = []
    a = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4', 'y5']
    for i in a:
        i = np.random.uniform(s, t, 10)
        s, t = s+10, t+10
        z.append(i)
    y = np.concatenate(z)
    return pd.Series(y)
```

Thanks everyone for showing interest....!

Comment: Move that `np.concatenate(z)` outside of the loop.  You don't need to do it every iteration.  Just do it once on a whole list of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify the function like this:

```
def colm(p, q, chunk_len=10):
    x = np.arange(0,5 * chunk_len)
    x = pd.DataFrame({'x':x})

    # just random uniform distributions in differnt range

    ys = [np.random.uniform(p_, q_, chunk_len) for p_, q_ in zip(p, q)]

    y = np.concatenate(ys)

    return x, pd.Series(y)
```

You can now use it as

```
x, y = colm([10, 20, 0, 30, 13], [15, 25, 5, 13, 17])
```

Comment: I do not want to repeat : y1 = np.random.uniform(10,15,chunk_len)
    y2 = np.random.uniform(20,25,chunk_len)
    y3 = np.random.uniform(0,5,chunk_len)
    y4 = np.random.uniform(30,32,chunk_len)
    y5 = np.random.uniform(13,17,chunk_len), that is why I am trying to write a function

Comment: You should leave the initial analysis of OP's problem in your question, with slight modifications.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not sure - I originally understood that the OP is passing x and y as "output parameters", which are "copied" by assigning them to s and t. I don't think that was the intent (although there's a superfluous renaming still going on). Do you understand it differently?

Comment: I understood that too. I think you shouldn't remove that part of your answer

Comment: @MadPhysicist The thing is, based on their comment, I now think it was an attempt to pass vectors of means and variances, and not output parameters. Sorry to have changed the answer (feel free to unvote it), but I just don't think that explanation is relevant anymore.